# Unknown column 'CARRE_ID' in 'field list' Error Code: 1054

Tags: mysql, jpa, mysql-error-1054

im trying to learn JAVA Persistent API with Eclipselink and MySQL, and this error comes up when i want to print a table in the IDE.

I try assign a @Column(name='CARRE_ID') but i get a error of ilegal start expretion. Same with @JoinColumn.

Can anybody tell me what im doing worng, pleas?  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEn1I.png)
@Column(name='carreid')

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUOnZ.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.